# how to retrive decimal values like 0.00000000 from excel sheet using java in selenium?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi, sqldatatypes

I have a column name BuyQuantity and it has values like as shown below:-

**BuyQuantity**
0.00000000
0.00000001
0.00000002
0.00000003
0.00000004
0.00000005

And i want to extract exact value as shown above and compare with some values which are again double.

I tried getting the value as below: -

String buy = r.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
total = Double.parseDouble(buy); // but i only get "0.0" as a value and not the entire value such as 0.00000000

I would appreciate if someone helps me in this.

Thank you!!!

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is probably caused due to parseDouble. I doubt this would happen  with 0.0000001 and etc

Comment: may i know how to resolve it please!!

Comment: @KrishnaJamadar - Can you confirm one thing 'buy' String comes in correct format from excel i.e. 0.00000 format ?

Comment: @AmitJain yes amit

Answer (score 0):

Try like this using `BigDecimal` and `DecimalFormat` classes.
It shows output as 0.000000000005

To compare 2 `BigDecimal` objects we can use `compareTo` method.

If first object is greater then return type is 1

If second object is greater then return type is -1

If both objects are equal then return type is 0

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class DoubleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String str =  "0.000000000005";
    String str2 = "0.000000000025";
    BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(str);
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.000000000000");
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(decimal));
    BigDecimal decimal2 = new BigDecimal(str2);
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat2 = new DecimalFormat("0.000000000000");
    System.out.println(decimalFormat2.format(decimal2));

    System.out.println(decimal.compareTo(decimal2));

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Amit, Thank you very much!! It is working.Thanks a lot.

Comment: i have one more issue when i am comparing two decimal numbers i.e. if(decimal < decimal2), it is giving me error as **"The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) java.math.BigDecimal, java.math.BigDecimal"**, will you please help me with this also.please.

Comment: @KrishnaJamadar - I have added solution to second question also. Please accept this answer now as you said it rightly answer to the question you asked.

Comment: it worked for me when i did this if(decimal.compareTo(decimal1) < 0.00050000).But your solution was really helpful for me.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KrishnaJamadar - As you stated above, please accept this as answer so that it will be beneficial for other who are reading this question. Thanks

Comment: Your given solution has solved my problem. @amit-jain

Comment: @KrishnaJamadar - Please read this page how to accept an answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: i tried doing that but it says! "**Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.**" :-(